# sql server SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

So I'm trying to format a column in a stored procedure, if the value is " boxter s" I want it to be retrieved as "Boxter S" I've sorted the 1st capital letter but I'm having trouble using the CASE statement to make the last letter a capital letter a capital if there is a space in the value. Not all values have a space hence the CASE statement and if there is a space there will only be one with one letter preceding it. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    CASE UPPER(LEFT(m.model, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(m.model, 2, LEN(m.manufacturer))) 
    WHEN m.model = % + ' ' 
    THEN UPPER(RIGHT(m.model, 1))
    END AS Model
```

Comment: What about upper(right(field, 1))?

Comment: I don't want the last letter of each column to be capitalised unless there is a space, so if the INPUT parameter is "hurrican" I dont want it to become "HurricaN". Unless I've missed your point, in which case could you care to past my code and show me what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
 select case when substring(model, len(model) - 2, 1) = ' ' then formatted
 else model end model
```

Work on the case logic and the formatting separately.

Comment: I think I made it overly complicated, thanks for this It works well